# IP of Web server stays in URL instead of showing Domain Name

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

So lets say I have the Domain Name "www.example.com" and have a "http-redirect" to server "1.1.1.1" where apache2 is running on Ubuntu 14.04 Server amd64. 
I have all my web files on the server and they are working perfect.
What is not working right is the URL. Instead of "www.example.com/sites.php" if have "1.1.1.1/sites.php". How can I fix this?
What I did so far:
Disabled the default Virtual Host and created a new one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin bla  
    ServerName example.com  
    ServerAlias www.example.com  
    DocumentRoot /var/www  
    ErrorLog ...  
    CustomLog ...  
</VirtualHost>
```

(It's typed, since I can't copy from my console..)

I tried to enter in the /etc/hosts

```
1.1.1.1   www.example.com
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you have two servers? One with domain name www.example.com and second that doesn’t have domain name, only IP address and you are doing http-redirect from www.example.com to 1.1.1.1? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Well, the reason that you see IP address in your browser is that http-redirect is pointing directly to to IP address, there's no domain name to display. Is your goal to enforce browser to display domain name of first server while serving web pages from second? Because that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Is your goal to enforce browser to display domain name of first server while serving web pages from second?
That's what i want to do. Is there no way that i can do this? Because I have the 2 server on different Hosters.

Comment: Well than this is certainly not the way, redirect will tell browser to go to another web-page (in your case 1.1.1.1). It acts same way as if you clicked link manually.

Comment: What can I do then?
I had my webfiles on the server with the domain name first, but I don't have much rights there, so I switched to this new one where I only have the IP.

Comment: If you are owner of the domain name you can have it changed so it will now point to your new server

Comment: I have something like A/AAAA-record on my Domain Name Server. Should I  enter there the IP of my new Server? And i get a warning that says that CNAME records are only supported for Subdomains. Will this work anyways then?

Comment: Nevermind it already works. THANKS alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, the reason that you see IP address in your browser is that http-redirect is pointing directly to to IP address, there's no domain name to display.
 Redirect just tells browser to go elsewhere and browser then fetches website from supplied URL, same as if you'd click on a link. If you redirect URL to 1.1.1.1/sites.php than that is what you will see in browser.